# Lower and upper bound for the area of a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, area, quadrilateral

Giving sides $a, b, c, d$ is not enough to obtain the area of a quadrilateral because there are many quadrilaterals possible with these 4 lengths.

Question: are there well-known **lower and upper bound for the area of a (non-crossed) quadrilateral, given the 4 sides?**

$$m(a,b,c,d) = \min_{Q \in\ \{non\,crossed\ quadrilaterals\\\qquad of\ sides\ a, b,c,d\}} Area(Q)$$

and idem for the max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Bretschneider’s formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bretschneider%27s_formula)

$$K={\sqrt  {(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)-abcd\cdot \cos ^{2}\left({\frac  {\alpha +\gamma }{2}}\right)}}$$

when $a,b,c,d$ are fixed, the area depends only on $\cos(\alpha + \gamma)$, where $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are opposite included angles and $s$ is the semiperimeter. So, we have to find values of $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ that make $\alpha + \gamma$ as close as possible to $\pi/2$ and $\pi$.

The quadrilateral [can be made cyclic](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/Constructions/CyclicQuadrilateral.shtml#construction), which gives us $\alpha+\gamma = \pi$. This minimizes $\cos(\alpha + \gamma)$ and hence maximizes the area.

The maximal possible area is therefore

$${\sqrt  {(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)}}.$$

Comment: Thanks @bubba. I edited to add the area formula for future reference, and a conclusion about the maximal area.

Comment: Last questions @bubba: 1) given $a, b, c, d$, can we *always* build a cyclic quadrilateral with these 4 lengths?  2) Any idea about the minimal possible area?

Comment: @basj if we get a quadrilateral, we also get a compkex cyclic quadrilateral (maximizes the area) and maybe a "crossed" cyclic quadrilateral too. Need longest side < sum of the other three sides.

Comment: @OscarLanzi I edited the question to specify I exclude crossed quadrilaterals.

Comment: Can we always build a cyclic quadrilateral?  The link I provided suggests that we can. I don’t see any obvious restrictions in the construction given there. But I admit that I didn’t read it very carefully.